# Where to find new class reference or function of deprecated one?

Tags: codex, deprecation

After upgrading from WordPress 3.5.2 to 3.6.1, with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` a site of mine's showing warning for some deprecated codes throughout the site. Some of 'em are generated from my codes, and some of 'em are from plugins I'm using.

In some of the messages, the debug process shows me what function to use instead, but in some cases, it's not.

So, it becomes difficult for me to find a new code that replaces the deprecated one.

<sub>**Note:** I'm a Wikipedian, and a Codex editor also.</sub>
Suppose, in Codex we can find all the deprecated codes [here in this category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:Deprecated_Functions). Some of them are well cited, with the new codes that replaces the deprecated one, but some of 'em are not, i.e.: [this one](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar_widget) <sup>(as on [this revision](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar_widget&oldid=97420)</sup>).

With this scenario, we know that some of the functions are replaced with another functions, while some other functions are replaced by a parameter of another different function. So, it's a bit unpredictable *which one can be used instead on this one*.

In this scenario, I think we need to find a place where we can sort all the deprecated functions with their new solutions, in a list. If such a thing is not available just now, we can make a separate page in Codex.

#### Edit

I may not clear with the motive of the question, I want a list like below:

```
+===========================+==============================+
|       DEPRECATED CODE     |            NEW CODE          |
+===========================+==============================+
|       `get_usermeta`      |         `get_user_meta`      |
| `register sidebar widget` | `wp_register_sidebar_widget` |
|            ...            |              ...             |
+===========================+==============================+
```

Comment: This reads more like call to action than _question_. :) There probably isn't one. New function reference for wordpress org is being developed, go suggest it as a feature there?

Comment: @Rarst: *This reads more like call to action than question.* - may be u r ri8. :) and *go suggest it*, can we have a link please?

Comment: [developer.WordPress.org Specification](http://make.wordpress.org/meta/2013/08/14/developer-wordpress-org-specification/)

Comment: `upgrading from WordPress 5 to 6.1` did you mean from 3.5.x to 3.6.1?

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu: Thanks for the clarification. I've corrected that now.

Comment: I edited my question with an example of what I actually demanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated functions are listed in the following files.

```
/wp-includes/deprecated.php
/wp-admin/includes/deprecated.php
/wp-includes/pluggable-deprecated.php
/wp-includes/ms-deprecated.php
/wp-admin/includes/ms-deprecated.php
```

As to whether the Codex is updated with the above I have no idea, but like always.. when in doubt look into the actual core code. Use an IDE or text editor that has a good *find in files* search, so you can quickly figure out what is going on over the whole codebase.